# How to continue text in next line in framebox?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, text-manipulation

I have written text in the framebox but it does not continue in the next line rather it keeps on adding the next in the same line and the resulting text is outside the box.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}
\framebox(500,360)[t]{\textbf{XX.INTERPRETIVE SUMMARY:}\textit{\begin{tiny}Briefly describe client global preferences/hopes for recovery,your clinical summary,\end{tiny}}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A tip: If you indent your code by four spaces, it *shows* as code on the page. Or you can do like I did when editing your post: Select the code, then hit the button marked {}. (And as for the question itself, you probably want some kind of `\parbox` to go inside the `\framebox`.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with `tcolorbox`, having a title attached to the upper box.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{summarybox}[1][]{%
  enhanced,
  sharp corners,
  colback=white,
  coltitle=black,
  fonttitle={\normalfont\bfseries},
  title={INTERPRETIVE SUMMARY:\quad},
  attach title to upper,
  fontupper={\itshape\tiny},
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{summarybox}
  Briefly describe client global preferences/hopes for recovery,your clinical summary.

  \blindtext[2]
\end{summarybox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you need a simple framed text, you could use `framed` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{mwe}% for testing purpose only

\begin{document}
    \begin{framed}
    \noindent\textbf{XX.INTERPRETIVE SUMMARY:}\itshape\tiny Briefly describe client global preferences/hopes for recovery,your clinical summary,
    \blindtext[2]% for testing purpose only
   \end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image]